# Should we have custom "Page not Found - 404 error" page?

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't we be having a customized error message:

[image]

Something like a sports blooper perhaps?

Comment: If we are starting a list of sports bloopers for custom error messages, here is my submission: http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/sanchez.gif

Comment: @edmastermind29 - [This](http://resources1.news.com.au/images/2010/09/17/1225925/467405-fox-sports-404-page.jpg) would be one of my favorite one..

Comment: @hims056 Excellent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All grainy (beta) sites have the same 404 page. When the site is launched it will get its own theme. And it will get its own 404 page.

So when our site launches, we will have custom [404](https://sports.stackexchange.com/404) and [error](https://sports.stackexchange.com/error) pages.